# Pick a Random Word On a Single Line In Python?

Tags: python, printing, random

How would I pick a single line and pick all the words on that line and then print them to the screen using a set. This is what I have so far:

```
import random

test = ['''
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
''']
print (random.choice(test))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does exactly what you're asking:

```
print random.choice(test[0].split('\n'))
line 5
```

I have a feeling you're looking to do a little more than that, though.

Comment: Why `test[0]`? This will give you the first character of `test`.

Comment: Copying and pasting my code beneath his code I get the following output:
In [7]: print random.choice(test[0].split('\n'))
line 3

In [8]: print random.choice(test[0].split('\n'))
line 1
Tim, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to pick them randomly without replacement; if all you do is pick words randomly, with something like

```
do until set empty
   pick a random word and print it
```

it would (a) not terminate, and (b) repeat words on average every 1/n times for n words.

It would be tempting to use a Python set, but inconveniently there's no obvious way to pick a random item from the set since it's not ordered.  (You might make a case that `set#pop` will work since it takes the arbitrary next item, but if I were grading I wouldn't give that full credit.)  On the other hand, the description says a set.

So I'd do something like this:

First put the items into a list.  Note that what you have puts one string with 10 lines into the list,, that is your list has length 1.  I'd bet you're better off initializing like

```
words = [ "test 1","test 2" # and so on
]
```

Next, select your items using `choice` as

```
word = random.choice(words)
```

Print it

```
print word
```

and remove it from the list

```
words.remove(word)
```

Put that in a loop that continues until you run out of words.  You get something like:

```
>>> import random
>>> words = ['a', 'b', 'c' ]
>>> while len(words) > 0:
...    word = random.choice(words)
...    print word
...    words.remove(word)
... 
b
a
c
```

gnibbler points out that you could also have

```
import random
words = [ ... ]
shuf = random.shuffle(words)
for i in shuf: 
   print i
```

but that doesn't treat the list as a set; it depends on there being an implicit order set by shuffle.

Comment: FTFY: There's no '`println`' in Python, and `len()` is a free function.  I think you were coding in Ruby by mistake?

Comment: Getting old isn't for sissies.

Comment: because this version has an obvious termination expression and seems simpler.  Also (he said after writing an update) it doesn't treat the list as a set, since shuffle depends on ordered elements.